# Configured a workflow to create a document

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, content-type

I've configured a workflow to create a document set item based on a particular content type.

My workflow creates the item successfully, but when selecting the created item, the docsethomepage displays a message at the top of the screen:

> Content type that are available to this Document set have added or
>   removed. Update the Document set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the `Update the Document Set` available as a link. I assume clicking the link removes the message (/warning)?

This message appears, when your Document Set has changed and it needs to be provisioned again. Provisioning does the following as per [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ee587723.aspx):

> Updates the document set item with any changes made to allowed content types for its content type. The method also adds the newly added content types to the list so that they are allowed in it.

The following PowerShell script provisions all of your Document Sets in a library:

```
$webURL = "http://sp.site.com"
$web = Get-SPWeb $webURL
$library = $web.Lists["Name of the Document Library"]
foreach($item in $library.Items | Where-Object {$_.Folder -ne $null})
{
    $docSet = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::GetDocumentSet($item.Folder)
    $docSet.Provision()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Moe. Any idea or solution using out of the box ?

Comment: @Sara after all this is a quite trivial solution with little to no risks. By staying at the SP page, actually when you click the `Update the Document Set`, it does do a provision job on the background, but yet calls for doing it again for each Document Set you have. The PS option automates this, leaving the message to history at once.

Comment: Also @Sara, looking the history of your asked questions, I think you should have a look at some of the SharePoint.SE's informative Help documentations, such as [**What should I do when someone answers my question?**](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). We here want to encourage users to promote if their questions have been answered by accepting the answer, as others looking for help with the same issue now or later can then refer to the given answers.

Comment: @Sara just to put emphasis on something: if someone answers your question so that it solves your problem, the answer should be marked as an accepted answer. You haven't marked a single answer as an accepted answer despite having tens of questions asked. You should go through your asked questions and find if there's an answer worthy of accepting, and accept it.